# Why does QPrinterInfo::availablePrinters() return an empty list on some PCs with printers?

Tags: windows, qt

Both `QPrinterInfo::availablePrinters()` and `QPrinterInfo::availablePrinterNames()` return an empty list on Windows PCs that nevertheless show printers when displayed in the Control Panel ➔ Devices & Printers.

The printers are not connected to the computer. I would at least expect Qt to display the "Microsoft Print to PDF". This is also failing on PCs with WiFi printer connections.

This works on PCs with printers, either connected directly, or over a network.

Any suggestions on how to get a Printer dialog to display, that is populated with the same list of printers as a native app?

```
QString buf;
QStringList allPrintersName = QPrinterInfo::availablePrinterNames();
QList <QString>::const_iterator sit;
for(sit = allPrintersName.cbegin(); sit != allPrintersName.cend(); sit++)
    buf += *sit + "\n";
QMessageBox(QMessageBox::NoIcon, "Printer Names", buf).exec(); // empty message

buf = "";
QList<QPrinterInfo> allPrintersInfo = QPrinterInfo::availablePrinters();
QList <QPrinterInfo>::const_iterator pit;
for(pit = allPrintersInfo.cbegin(); pit != allPrintersInfo.cend(); pit++)
    buf += pit->printerName() + "\n";
QMessageBox(QMessageBox::NoIcon, "QPrinterInfo", buf).exec(); // empty message
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by not knowing that I needed to install the following in my app folder:

```
..\printsupport\windowsprintersupport.dll
```

Answered here:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/39319/solved-qprinterinfo-availableprinters-don-t-list-available-printers

https://forum.qt.io/post/197518